# How to get the Database Details in custom php file Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, database

I added the custom.php file in the magento-2 root folder and I want to get the database details from env.php file

```
'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'dbname' => 'magento',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '4gile-123',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
```

Can any please help to get database details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the magento `vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php`

Check the function **loadConfigFile**

```
if ($fileDriver->isExists($path . '/' . $pathConfig)) {
    $configResult = include $path . '/' . $pathConfig;
    if (is_array($configResult)) {
        $result = array_replace_recursive($result, $configResult);
    }
}
```

So I will keep it simple you can try this code in your custom.php file placed in magento root folder.

```
$envFilePath = __DIR__ . '/app/etc/env.php';
$configResult = include $envFilePath;
echo "<pre>";print_r($configResult);die;
```

**Note:** Make sure you have permission and you know what you are doing :)